# Not all Red-Black trees are balanced?

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees

Intuitively, "balanced trees" should be trees where left and right sub-trees at each node must have "approximately the same" number of nodes.

Of course, when we talk about red-black trees*(see definition at the end) being balanced, we actually mean that they are *height* balanced and in that sense, they are balanced.

Suppose we try to formalize the above intuition as follows:

> **Definition:** A Binary Tree is called $\mu$-balanced, with $0 \le \mu \leq \frac{1}{2}$, if for every node $N$, the inequality
>
> $$ \mu \le \frac{|N_L| + 1}{|N| + 1} \le 1 - \mu$$
>
> holds and for every $\mu' \gt \mu$, there is some node for which the above statement fails. $|N_L|$ is the number of nodes in the left sub-tree of $N$ and $|N|$ is the number of nodes under the tree with $N$ as root (including the root).

I believe, these are called *weight-balanced* trees in some of the literature on this topic.

One can show that if a binary tree with $n$ nodes is $\mu$-balanced (for a constant $\mu \gt 0$), then the height of the tree is $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$, thus maintaining the nice search properties.

So the question is:

> Is there some $\mu \gt 0$ such that every big enough red-black tree is $\mu$-balanced?

---

The definition of Red-Black trees we use (from Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al):

A binary search tree, where each node is coloured either red or black and

- The root is black
- All NULL nodes are black
- If a node is red, then both its children are black.
- For each node, all paths from that node to descendant NULL nodes have the same number of black nodes.

Note: we don't count the NULL nodes in the definition of $\mu$-balanced above. (Though I believe it does not matter if we do).

Comment: @Aryabhata: what's with the uniqueness ($\mu'>\mu$) in your edit? I'm fine with the fact that $\frac13$-balanced implies $\frac14$-balanced. I don't think you should have to find the _exact_ $\mu$ to prove height is $O(\log n)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Furthermore, you require a negative statement to provide a counterexample chain with one tree for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Any infinite chain that is non-decreasing in node size would be sufficient, wouldn't it?

Comment: @jmad: Without the $\mu'$ edit, every tree is trivially $0$-balanced and so we have a trivial no answer to the question. I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: @Raphael: I don't understand. The node size of the $n^{th}$ tree is $n$. You are saying it does not matter what tree we pick for $RB_n$ and that $\mu_n \to 0$? Does not seem obvious to me, and that is what the question is about!

Comment: @Aryabhata: oh I see: that's because your "no answer" does not correspond to (my reformulation of) your question. I'll suggest an edit.

Comment: An earlier version of this question claimed that the runtime of a recursive algorithm on a red-black tree which does linear amount of work at each step is not necessarily $O(n\log n)$.  This claim was incorrect; [height-balance implies that the depth of an $n$-node red-black tree is $O(\log n)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Proof_of_asymptotic_bounds).  Thus, if you perform $O(n)$ work at each level of the tree, the total work is $O(n \log n)$.

Comment: @Jmad: I don't think the edit is the same. For instance, you could have a sequence of Trees of $2^n$ nodes for which the $\mu$s go to $0$ and that would be a counter example to your statement, but not to the original statement. Perhaps your formulation is better, though.

Comment: @JeffE: Thanks! +1 to your comment :-)

Comment: @Aryabhata: All you need for a counter-proof are arbitrary big trees that undercut any proposed $\mu$; you formulate something stronger. Does my answer clarify what I mean?

Comment: @Raphael: I wanted something stronger (in fact I believe Knuth's has some exercise on this. Yes this was a seeding question). But I can reformulate so that both the answers below are 100% the intended answer. Unfortunately jmad had done that and I had rejected the edit.

Comment: @jmad: Will you be willing to suggest an edit again? Apologies...

Comment: @Aryabhata: I think a "sparse" chain is enough; I would be surprised if it could not be filled out. We do the same when analysing divide and conquer algorithms, by the way; to refute a limit, one refuting subsequence is enough. Or do I miss something of your goal?

Comment: @Raphael: Well, consider the statement, all numbers have no more than three factors. You pick the primes and say it is true :-) Of course, since this is kind of open ended, we can formulate the question as we want and besides, as you say, we can probably pad it out, and I agree that it would probably not be that difficult. You are not refuting the limit part, you are supporting it...

Comment: @Aryabhata: The thing is, you claim something *for all sufficiently large* trees that does not hold; so, in order to refute that claim *some* sufficiently large trees contradict the statement.

Comment: @Raphael: Actually the original form of the question wasn't like this, and an edit was made by someone else. Though based on all your comments, I am now inclined to change the question. Just don't want to offend jmad by doing it myself (I had rejected an edit from jmad earlier).

Comment: @Jmad: I made similar edits which I rejected earlier. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Aryabhata: no problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Claim**: Red-black trees can be arbitrarily un-$\mu$-balanced.

**Proof Idea**: Fill the right subtree with as many nodes as possible and the left with as few nodes as possible for a given number $k$ of black nodes on every root-leaf path.

**Proof**: Define a sequence $T_k$ of red-black trees so that $T_k$ has $k$ black nodes on every path from the root to any (virtual) leaf. Define $T_k = B(L_k, R_k)$ with

- $R_k$ the complete tree of height $2k - 1$ with the first, third, ... level colored red, the others black, and
- $L_k$ the complete tree of height $k-1$ with all nodes colored black.

Clearly, all $T_k$ are red-black trees.

For example, these are $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$, respectively:

---

[image: T_1]
<sup>[[source](https://github.com/akerbos/sesketches/blob/gh-pages/src/cs_342_1.dot)]</sup>

---

[image: T_2]
<sup>[[source](https://github.com/akerbos/sesketches/blob/gh-pages/src/cs_342_2.dot)]</sup>

---

[image: T_3]
<sup>[[source](https://github.com/akerbos/sesketches/blob/gh-pages/src/cs_342_3.dot)]</sup>

---

Now let us verify the visual impression of the right side being *huge* compared to the left. I will not count virtual leaves; they do not impact the result.

The left subtree of $T_k$ is complete and always has height $k-1$ and therefore contains $2^k - 1$ nodes. The right subtree, on the other hand, is complete and has height $2k - 1$ and thusly contains $2^{2k}-1$ nodes. Now the $\mu$-balance value for the root is

$\qquad \displaystyle \frac{2^k}{2^k + 2^{2k}} = \frac{1}{1 + 2^k} \underset{k\to\infty}{\to} 0$

which proves that there is no $\mu > 0$ as requested.

Answer (score 15):

**No.**  Consider a red-black tree with the following special structure.

- The left subtree is a complete binary tree with depth $d$, in which every node is black.
- The right subtree is a complete binary tree with depth $2d$, in which every node at odd depth is red, and every node at even depth is black.

It's straightforward to check that this is a valid red-black tree.  But the number of nodes in the right subtree ($2^{2d+1}-1$) is roughly the *square* of the number of nodes in the left subtree ($2^{d+1}-1$).

Comment: +1: Thanks! But the number of nodes is of the from $2^{2d+1} + 2^{d+1} - 1$. Can we perhaps 'pad' these sufficiently to get a tree a given size $n$? (It looks like that should be do-able).

Comment: You already have a counterexample for infinitely many $n$, so why bother?.  But I suppose if you wanted to, you could add more red nodes to the left subtree, or take some red nodes out of the right subtree.

Comment: @JeffE: Basically the counterexample chain would then be a 'dense' subset, rather than a 'sparse' subset. Perhaps I will change the formulation of the question.