# Example of height-balanced tree that is not weight-balanced

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees, balanced-search-trees

Following this question : [Two definitions of balanced binary trees](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/two-definitions-of-balanced-binary-trees)

I am having a hard time making sense of the proofs provided and I'm looking for an example of a simple binary tree that is *height-balance*d but not *weight-balanced*.

This would mean that we could clearly see the height differences of two sub-trees being more than one while the maximum depth difference of any two leave nodes would never be more than one.

Does such an example exist?

**EDIT:** This question was asked because I misunderstood the *inner-node* concept. I was looking for a tree example where the height of two sub trees differed by more than one while the the maximum depth and minimum depth had a difference of no more than one.

Comment: You should try harder.

Comment: See [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/342/not-all-red-black-trees-are-balanced?rq=1) and [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/421/avl-trees-are-not-weight-balanced?rq=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a complete binary tree of height 2 (with 7 vertices), and add two children to the two left leaves. The tree is height-balanced but the root is not weight-balanced.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was confused about the definition of "inner-nodes".