# RB trees from any balanced BST?

Tags: trees, binary-search-trees, red-black-trees

Given any perfectly balanced binary search tree, is it always possible to assign a coloring to the nodes so that it becomes a Red-Black tree? If so, how do you prove this, and if false, what would be a counterexample?

Recall the following definitions.

**Perfectly balanced node**: A node of a binary tree is said to be *perfectly balanced* if the absolute difference in the number of vertices in its left subtree and its right subtree is atmost 1.

**Perfectly Balanced Tree**: A binary tree is called *perfectly balanced* if all its nodes are perfectly balanced.

**Trivial Fact**: The height of a perfectly balanced tree is $\Theta (\log n)$ where $n$ is the number of nodes in the tree.

Comment: You mean really perfectly balanced, where all levels of the tree are filled? Then you can colour all nodes black.

Comment: @HendrikJan I've added the definition of perfectly balanced tree in the question.

Comment: Any AVL-tree can be coloured Red-Black (the wikipedia page on Red-Black trees states this, without references). As your perfect balance is more strict than AVL-trees, that answers your question. I find it hard to locate explicit algorithms that do the colouring. One suggestion was given by  [Karolis](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/65811/4287) here.