# Is there a binary search tree datastructure which can avoid becoming badly weight-balanced?

Tags: data-structures, search-trees

This is a follow-up question of "[Not all Red-Black trees are balanced?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/342/not-all-red-black-trees-are-balanced)" and "[AVL trees are not weight-balanced?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/421/avl-trees-are-not-weight-balanced)".$\def\le{\leqslant}\def\ge{\geqslant}$

> **Definition:** For a rooted tree $T$ and a vertex $v \in V(T)$, let $L_T(v)$ be the number of nodes in the left-subtree from $v$, and $N_T(v)$ be the number of nodes in the subtree rooted at $v$. We say that $T$ is *$\mu$-balanced*, with $0 \le \mu \le \frac{1}{2}$, if for every node $v \in V(T)$ the inequality
>   $$ \mu \le \frac{L_T(v) + 1}{N_T(v) + 1} \le 1 - \mu$$
>   holds, and if $\mu$ is minimal subject to this inequality holding.

(These are apparently also known as  *weight-balanced* trees in some of the literature.) A tree which is $\mu'$-balanced for some $\mu' < \mu$, we will say is **μ-imbalanced**.

The above-linked posts essentially show that neither [AVL trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), nor [Red-Black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), can be guaranteed to be $\mu$-balanced for any $\mu > 0$: that is, for any such $\mu$, one can provide a sequence of inputs to be inserted so that the resulting tree is $\mu$-imbalanced.

**Question.** Is there any binary search tree structure, with the usual characteristics of $O(\log n)$ insertion and search time, and some $m > 0$, such that the tree will always be $\mu$-balanced for some $\mu > m$?

Comment: I'd say that the reason why $\mu$-balanced trees are rarely used: they require too much overhead when balancing them, with a little gain. Consider the example in [this answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/375/2448): The tree has height $2k+2$. It's left subtree has $2^k-1$ nodes and its right subtree has $2^{2k+1}-1$ nodes, so overall it has $2^{2k+1}+2^k-1$. If we put the same number of nodes into a perfectly balanced tree, it will still have height $2k+2$. Since the height is what determines operation costs, we gain nothing, we only spend much more time re-balancing.

Comment: @PetrPudlák: Indeed, reading [*Binary search trees of bounded balance* (Nievergelt+Reingold)](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=804906) in Aryabhata's answer, I'm struck by the oddness of the idea of searching by traversing the entire data structure. I'm not sure under what circumstances one might want to do such a thing, which wouldn't suggest either a simpler or a more elaborate data structure instead. If finding the path to the sought-for element is easy, as in a typical implementation of BSTs on an ordered set, it's height but not weight which matters; but as a combinatoricist I'm curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I believe there is (though I don't remember the details of the paper to confirm).

This is the original paper which dealt with that:

> Nievergelt J. and Reingold E.M., "[Binary search trees of bounded
>   balance](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=804906)", Proceedings of the fourth annual ACM symposium on Theory of
>   computing, pp 137--142, 1972

Here is a [page on weight-balanced trees](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/weight-balanced-tree/) which seems to have some more information and mentions their usage in functional languages.

This paper: [On Average number of rebalanced operations in weight balanced trees](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/mehlhorn22.pdf), seems to be investigating the number of rebalancing operations in weight balanced trees.

I also seem to remember that one Knuth's Art of ... books had a reference to the above Reingold paper (perhaps in the exercises).