# Treaps are expected weight-balanced?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, search-trees, heaps

In a [previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/342/not-all-red-black-trees-are-balanced) there was a definition of *weight-balanced* and a question regarding red-black trees.

This question is to ask the similar question, but for [treaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap).

The question is:

> Is there some $ \mu > 0 $ such that the expectation of $ \frac{|N_L| + 1}{|N| + 1} $ not less than $ \mu $ and not greater than $ 1 - \mu $ in treaps that the number of nodes is big enough?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Can you edit the question to make it self-contained?  Also expectation over what random process, exactly?  Do you want that to hold for all nodes of all big enough treaps?  What does it mean to say "all treaps" when you're taking an expectation over treaps?  The previous question didn't have any notion of randomness so I think you're going to need to set up that aspect of the problem carefully.

Comment: @D.W. Better now?

Comment: Interesting question, but: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Have you worked through the analysis of the expected height of treaps in detail?

Comment: @D.W. I would assume the same model that is used for expected height? That is, permutations with i.i.d. uniform "priorities"; it's straight-forward to show that the permutation is irrelevant for the resulting tree (there is exactly one treap for every key-priority sequence, assuming unique keys).

Comment: @Raphael, nope, not clear to me yet!  The question is still not self-contained.  What's $N_L$ and $N$?  Expectation over what random process?  If the intent is to ask about a random process with a sequence of insertions with disjoint iid keys, chosen uniformly at random from some range of integers 1..m, that would be worth documenting.  If so, I would imagine the answer might depend on $m$.  In any case, this should be specified in the question.

Comment: Also, if I understand what's being asked, the question seems to have a trivial 'yes' answer, which makes me suspect this isn't what Yuyang Zhao meant to ask.  Take the limiting value of $\mathbb{E}[(|N_L|+1)/(|N|+1)]$ as $|N| \to \infty$; call it $v$.  Then $\mu = \min(v,1-v)$ seems to suffice.  Have I missed something?

Comment: @D.W. Neither that expected value nor the limit are guaranteed to exist, aren't they?  But I think I see your point; it's not clear what "expectation" means here. The weight-balancing fraction is defined per node, but our distribution is defined on treaps. The two don't go together. We need a statistic for whole treaps.